# How to use a variable which is used in an ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable

as you can see in the picture I'm setting up a table which shows all files from a specific path (later I'll implement a filter for pdf files only). First, all files are simultaneously shown, but I want to see each single file of the path during the build up of the table. So I've changed it to a array list, but there a two errors which I really couldn't resolve...

Hope that you can help me ;-)[image]

```
class FileModel extends AbstractTableModel implements FilenameFilter {   

String titles[] = new String[] { "Path" };
Class<?> types[] = new Class[] { String.class, String.class };
private List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>();

public FileModel() {
    this("C:\\");
}

public FileModel(String dir) {
    File pwd = new File(dir);
    setFileStats(pwd);
}

// Implement the methods of the TableModel interface we're interested
// in. Only getRowCount(), getColumnCount() and getValueAt() are
// required. The other methods tailor the look of the table.
@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return this.data.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return this.titles.length;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int c) {
    return this.titles[c];
}

@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c) {
    return this.types[c];
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int r, int c) {
    return this.data.get(r)[c];
}

// Our own method for setting/changing the current directory
// being displayed. This method fills the data set with file info
// from the given directory. It also fires an update event so this
// method could also be called after the table is on display.
public void setFileStats(File dir) {
    System.out.println("SET MY DIR " + dir);

    this.data = new ArrayList<>();

    this.fireTableDataChanged();

    String files[] = dir.list();

    this.data = new Object[files.length][this.titles.length];   **// Here error #1**

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        File tmp = new File(files[i]);

        this.data[i][0] = tmp.getAbsolutePath();                **// Here error #2**
    }        
    this.fireTableDataChanged();
}

@Override
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

**Here's the code of the JFrame windows:**

```
public class FileFrame extends JFrame {

protected FileModel fileModel = new FileModel();
{
    this.setSize(500, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    JTable FileTable = new JTable(this.fileModel);
    TableRowSorter<TableModel> TableRowSorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(this.fileModel);
    FileTable.setRowSorter(TableRowSorter);
    FileTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    FileTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    FileTable.setDefaultRenderer(Number.class, new BigRenderer(1000));
    JScrollPane JScrollPane = new JScrollPane(FileTable);
    getContentPane().add(JScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    final FileFrame FileFrame = new FileFrame();

    // Create menubar
    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    // Create JMenu object
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
    // Create JMenuItem object
    final JMenuItem openItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
    JMenuItem exititem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    // Add JMenuItem to JMenu
    menu.add(openItem);
    menu.add(exititem);
    // Add menu to menubar
    menubar.add(menu);
    // Add menubar to dialog
    FileFrame.setJMenuBar(menubar);
    // Show dialog
    FileFrame.setVisible(true);

    // Integrate ActionListener as anonymous class
    openItem.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public File savedPath;
        public final JFileChooser FileChooser = new JFileChooser("C:\\");

        // Initialize actionPerformed
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Generate choose file
            this.FileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            this.FileChooser.setDialogTitle("Selection of pdf directory");
            this.FileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            // Set the text
            this.FileChooser.setApproveButtonText("Open directory");
            // Set the tool tip
            this.FileChooser.setApproveButtonToolTipText("Select pdf directory ");
            if (this.savedPath != null)
                this.FileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(this.savedPath);
            int returnVal = this.FileChooser.showOpenDialog(openItem);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                this.savedPath = this.FileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                FileFrame.fileModel.setFileStats(this.savedPath);
            }
        }
    });

    // Integrate ActionListener as anonymous class
    exititem.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        // Initialize actionPerformed
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Close program
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: `but there a two errors which I really couldn't resolve` what errors are there?

Comment: `data` is a `List` not an array.

Comment: @Pphoenix
#1 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object[][] to List<Object[]>
#2 The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List<Object[]>

Comment: @peeskillet: Yeah I have declared data as Arraylist...

Comment: So why are you trying to access it like its an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to access `data` as though its an array

```
private List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
...
this.data = new Object[files.length][this.titles.length]; 
this.data[i][0] = tmp.getAbsolutePath();
```

But `data` is actually a `List<Object[]>`

So you might want to do

```
//data.add(new Object[files.length][this.titles.length]);
data.add(new Object[files.length]); // can only be one dimensional

 and 

((Object[])data.get(i))[0] = tmp.getAbsolutePath();
```

instead

See more on how to use `Lists` at [The List Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html)

---

**UPDATE**

Change your model code to this

```
String files[] = dir.list();

for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    File tmp = new File(files[i]);
    data.add(new Object[] { tmp.getAbsolutePath()}) ;           
}
```

All you need to do is add a new `Object[]` to the list (*inside* the loop) with just the file path, since that seems to be all you need. Don't add one before.

Comment: thank you for your help! My code is now without errors, but I'm not able to run the JFrame due of some exceptions...

Comment: Sems like a whole other problem for which we have no information for

Comment: Try posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the stacktrace, for further help

Comment: Jep I think so too. Well I didn't want to waste your time with the rest of the code from the JFrame (90 lines). Anyway thank you very much and when you still want to see the code than let me know.

Comment: I've just edited my post from above and added the rest of the code.

Comment: Switch `((Object[])data.get(i))[0]` to `((Object[])data.get(0))[i]`. Had it reversed. Don't know if it works the way you want. But they exception is gone. You may need to recheck your logic

Comment: PERFECT! It works, but now there's only one "file" displayed. That's strange. Well I recheck the logic...

Thanks :)

Comment: WOW! I'm overwhelmed. Now everything works. Thanks a million, I'm speechless. Have a nice day, greetings from Germany.